# Using custom Mac font with no file extension in Bootstrap

Tags: css, macos, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, sublimetext2

I want to use an amazing font a font-designer made for my organisation. The font is a Mac font with no file extension and Sublime Text 2 doesn't seem to recognise it. I am building a website with Bootstrap and want to use the font - how do I convert it to a woff?

I used the Mac terminal with the file -I command and it gives me:

```
application/x-empty; charset=binary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to answer this question - the only thing that worked was switching to a PC and using Cross Font.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into a webfont using the [Webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) by Font Squirrel. After that, you can add this into your CSS to get the font work.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: I did try font Squirrel an it didn't recognize the files